# Index Match Two Criteria With Max Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a three column data:

### Value | Status | Name

I need a formula that gives the name where row has the highest Value and Status is "Done". I have this so far:

```
=INDEX(Table[Name],MATCH(MAX(Table[Value]),Table[Value],0))
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need an array formula:

```
=INDEX(Table[Name],MATCH(1,INDEX((MAX(IF(Table[Status]="Done",Table[Value]))=Table[Value])*(Table[Status]="Done"),),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I thought for sure you would have gone the aggregate route on this one to avoid the CSE.  well CSE in disguise.  Was that because it was a table?  or were you feeling like mixing it up?

Comment: @ForwardEd because it was probably going to be a CSE formula with the double condition anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This is an option that hides the array function.  I was actually surprised how similar it was to Scott's answer when I was done.  I was basically bored out of my mind and needed something to do so I came up with the following to demonstrate you have option on how to achieve what you want.

```
=INDEX(ScottsTable[Name],MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,(ScottsTable[Status]="Done")*ScottsTable[Value],1),ScottsTable[Value],0))
```

First time for me playing with "Tables".  It was interesting watching the cell references change.

Proof of Concept - Tanks to Scott

[image: Proof of concept]

<sub>Please give any positive credit for this answer to Scott above.</sub>